# metrics(contrib) of tensorflow shows only limited attributes

Tags: tensorflow, roc, auc

I wanted to find auc value for the neural net model using
tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_auc() in tensorflow.
But tf.contrib.metrics. has no other option except auc_histogram(). There are lot of options available in tensorflow but nothing is availble for me. Could someone help me in fetching those attributes.

Comment: What is your Tensorflow version?

Comment: tensorflow version : 0.8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update TensorFlow to 0.9.

In version 0.8, `tf.contrib.metric` only has one function `auc_using_histogram()` available (see the [github directory](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r0.8/tensorflow/contrib/metrics/python/ops)).

Whereas in version 0.9, more function are available ([github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r0.9/tensorflow/contrib/metrics/python/ops)).

Comment: can i install with this command "$ sudo pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL"

Comment: Sure. If you have further questions, please open another question in StackOverflow